# InDesign Automation - possible to do without InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'd like to develop an InDesign template, then try to automate it via scripting and feeding it data via a CSV or an XML file. Currently, it seems that this solution will work if I have the desktop version of InDesign.

Is it possible for a web application to take the template, populate the template with data from a database, then provide either a PDF or InDesign file to be available for download? Is there some sort of server software I'd need to have to make this happen? Or perhaps a web service I could use?

Comment: I think that this is a job for Latex/Tex, so http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adobe does not allow to use InDesign Desktop this way, for this you need [InDesign Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesignserver.html).

You *can* create "InDesign" files without actually having InDesign, in the form of IDML. However, to "view" it or "convert to PDF" the end-user still needs InDesign. Without having InDesign, you can create IDML but you would not know how much text is going to fit in each frame and on each page. IDML is an abstract data format, and still relies on ID itself to actually 'render' the text.

Why are you considering InDesign at all? There are free PDF-backends that can translate your CSV into a PDF, such as [PdfBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/), and may be more suitable to your task.

Comment: I'm not wedded to InDesign. I just need to automate the creation of flyers that are being produced at a fairly regular basis. I started to explore InDesign since that seems to be a popular choice for print layout/design. As for outputting in PDF/InDesign, I assume these are formats printing companies can work with easily. Also, if there are problems with the automation, outputting in InDesign allows a user to make edits to fix the problems. Thoughts?

Comment: Any printer worth his salary will ask for PDFs, sending InDesign files around is a recipe for disaster. OTOH, manually editing afterwards *is* easier with a native ID file. I'm afraid you are on your own, weighing pro against con. But you're still not allowed to use desktop ID for a web service, and so that may be the definitive limiting factor.

Answer (score 0):

[EMC Document Sciences xPression](http://www.emc.com/case-management/document-sciences/xpression-enterprise-edition.htm) is what you need.

It can define a dynamic template using InDesign, and populate/publish the template with xml data in batches.

Answer (score 0):

You have dozens of ways to get such automation. Your only concern is in the visual rendering. If you have strong typographic and graphic concerns, InDesign Server is a first class tool. 
If the aspect is less critical, you can envision fillable pdf or XSL:fo.
Apart from that you also have W2P solutions that you can implement.